# Do the front end attachments from one lawn tractor brand work on another brand?

Tags: lawn-mower

I'm torn between two different brands' garden tractors; one has a 3-stage snowblower and other has a 2-stage, but that latter brand also has a manual front-end scoop and the former does not.

Are these sorts of accessories generally interchangeable?

Comment: It's going to be brand specific - some may be, others may not.  That said, the question is really brand specific even though you didn't mention a specific brand, and as such isn't really a good question for this venue.

Comment: All non-powered attachments are interchangeable if you're willing to build an adapter plate :-) . (I do know folks who go this route).  Swapping powered attachments is less likely to work, other than as discussed in Henry Jackson's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is maybe.

Some companies build tractors for many different brands. E.g. Husqvarna sells their own brand of riding mowers but also makes the current Craftsman line with only minor differences in the plastic body. So a lot of attachments between those two are interchangeable (and again, made by Husqvarna). I think they also make Poulan tractors.

MTD is another manufacturer that makes their own line in addition to others like Cub Cadet, Troy-Bilt, and the older Craftsman mowers.

John Deere I believe is not associated with other brands but I'm not sure.